# How to set second tab as selected when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have got a task to do jquery tab. Each tab has some special function.When loading the page it goes to the first tab.I want to set the second tab as selected> How can I do that?
My code is

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
     $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
      $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
        "selected": 2,
        "disabled": [1,2,3]
      });

    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
         $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
        }
        else{
             $('#tabs').tabs("disable", $(this).val());
        }
    });
    });
    });//]]>  

    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sachin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ganguly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Nithin</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  <form name="nithin">
  <b>Name</b>
  <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Sachin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Ganguly</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1">tabs-1 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2">tabs-2 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3">tabs-3 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-4" value="4">tabs-4 
<br>

    </body>


    </html>
```

You can see from http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have it disabled. Change to:

```
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,3]
  });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/2aQ2g/34/

**Update** To change the page based on submitted data you should modify what you output on the page at the server. If 2 was selected than do not put it in the disabled list.

**update 2** If you want the prevent the page from reloading on submit you need to do custom form handling:

```
 // Do custom submit handling : 
 $('form').unbind('submit').submit(function(e)
                     {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         // place logic here: 
                     }
 );
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/2aQ2g/37/

Comment: Actually I want not like that. I have a submit button on 2nd tab.When i press submit button the page must reloaded and the it goes to the first tab.

Comment: Here you mentioned about onload function. What about the submit button.When i press it goes to first tab

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", {"selected":1, "disabled": [0, 2, 3 ] });
)};
```

Comment: Actually I want not like that. I have a submit button on 2nd tab.When i press submit button the page must reloaded and the it goes to the first tab.

Comment: post your submit button code please..and you had not updated in your fiddle with the latest line of code..